# Apache Camel WebService consumer

Tags: java, spring, web-services, apache-camel

I have created a route

```
cxf:cxfEndpoint id="testEndpoint" address="http://localhost:9003/ws"
            serviceClass="pl.test.ws.testImpl"
            wsdlURL="/META-INF/wsdl/test.wsdl"
            endpointName="s:testSoap"
            serviceName="s:testService"
            xmlns:s = "https://test.pl/wsdl"/>
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
       <route>
         <from uri="direct:sendToTest" />
         <to uri="cxf:bean:testEndpoint" />
       </route>
</camelContext>
```

How can i `call` this webservice by putting object in the `direct:sendToTest` route?

I would like to be able to make a soap `request` some criteria will be met however I do not knew how can I put from `java` class message on the route.

can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ProducerTemplate` to send message to any Camel endpoint from Java code.

A little example from the getting started guide

- http://camel.apache.org/walk-through-an-example.html

And to get more familiar with Apache Camel I recommend people to read this article

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-source-integration-apache